# Tiling 10x10 grid with tetrominos

Tags: logical-deduction

I just wondering if you have a way to complete the task of "Tiling a 10x10 grid with tetrominos". I know this has been done before, but I was wondering if there are other methods?

Best regards Synne (Norway)

Comment: If my edit isn't the question you were trying to ask, make sure to roll it back. I was trying to clear it up a bit but may have changed the overall meaning by accident.

Comment: I’m VTCing as too broad because there are a staggering amount of different answers to this- my answer is only one of the many possible answers.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.  Unfortunately, this post doesn't meet the guidelines for this site, because it doesn't have criteria for *one demonstrably correct answer*.  While open-ended questions like this can be interesting, they don't fit the format of this site.  If you can reformulate it with criteria to determine **one** best answer, feel free to flag it for re-opening.

Comment: They probably meant to ask about tiling a $10\times10$ square with T-tetrominoes, in which case the [question is a duplicate](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11057/tiling-a-chessboard-with-tetrominos).

Answer (score 2):

> Use 5 2x2 tetrominoes to cover a 10x2 area, then use 20 1x4s to create 10 1x8 pieces, each covering one remaining row.